# Fluent Hibernate One-To-One mapping issue

Tags: c#-4.0, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

I am not sure how to map below given entities.

Below are the tables.

```
Employee { ID, Name, Role_ID } (Role_ID is foreign key from Role table)
Role     {Role_ID, Name }
```

Below are the classes:

```
class Employee
{
     public virtual string ID { get; set; }
     public virtual string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual Role EmpRole { get; set; }
}

class Role
{
     public virtual string RoleID { get; set; }
     public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Below are the Mappings:

```
  public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
  {
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Table("Employee");
        Id(x => x.ID, "ID");
        Map(x => x.Name, "NAME");
        //for relationship not sure which mapping to be used???  

    }
  }

  public class RoleMap : ClassMap<Role>
  {
    public RoleMap()
    {
        Table("Role");
        Id(x => x.RoleID, "ROLE_ID");
        Map(x => x.RoleID, "ROLE_ID");
        Map(x => x.Name, "ROLE_NAME");
        //For relationship not sure what to be used???? 
    }
  }
```

Scenario : One Employee will have one role. One Role can be assigned to multiple employee.

Please suggest me how to write the relationship for both entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing the most common scenario. The mapping in this case would be `many-to-one` which in fluent is represented with **`.References()`**

```
public EmployeeMap()
{
    Table("Employee");
    Id(x => x.ID, "ID");
    Map(x => x.Name, "NAME");
    References(x => x.EmpRole , "Role_ID");
}
```

The best overview *(I am aware about)* is available here:

#### [Mapping-by-Code - ManyToOne](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-manytoone.html) by Adam Bar

Suprisingly this post is not about fluent NHibernate but about **mapping by code**. The second half however, compares with fluent - and provides really comprehensive overivew. Small snippet:

```
References(x => x.PropertyName, "column_name")
    .Class<ClassName>()
    .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
    .Fetch.Join()
    .Update()
    .Insert()
    .ReadOnly()
    .Access.Field()
    .Unique()
    .OptimisticLock()
    .LazyLoad(Laziness.Proxy)
    .PropertyRef(x => x.PropertyRef)
    .NotFound.Ignore()
    .ForeignKey("column_fk")
    .Formula("arbitrary SQL expression")
    .Index("column_idx")
    .Not.Nullable()
    .UniqueKey("column_uniq");
```

In case you would search for NHibernate doc (fluent operates on top of it) you should check the:

#### [5.1.10. many-to-one](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone)

If you want Fluent-NHibernate doc:

- [Fluent mapping](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping)

Finally, if you like to see which Employees belong to each Role, you can extend your POCO:

```
class Role
{
     public virtual string RoleID { get; set; }
     public virtual string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And map it as a `<bag>`.

```
HasMany(x => x.Employees)
   .KeyColumn("Role_ID")
   .Inverse()
   .BatchSize(25)
```

See:

- [6.1. Persistent Collections](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections) *(NHibernate doc for `one-to-many`)*
- [Mapping-by-Code - Set and Bag](http://notherdev.blogspot.cz/2012/01/mapping-by-code-set-and-bag.html) - again by Adam Bar, second half about fluent